# Cannot find the field in the JSON string

Tags: scala, playframework

I have the following String:

```
val jsonString: String = """{"additionalProperties":{},"annotation":{"type":"getDetails","docId":"doi:10.1186-s13612-016-0045-3","tags":{"wellbeing":7,"mood":6,"memories":6,"tmr":3,"participants":3},"additionalProperties":{}}}"""
```

I want to extract `tags` and convert this field to a String. This is how I do it using playframework:

```
val parsedJson = Json.parse(jsonString)
val result = (parsedJson \ "tags").as[JsString].value
System.out.println(result)
```

This code gets stuck at the line `val result = (parsedJson \ "tags").as[JsString].value` and does not return any error message.

Therefore I have two questions:

1. What am I doing wrong? I would like to get `"tags":{"wellbeing":7,"mood":6,"memories":6,"tmr":3,"participants":3}`
2. How to avoid such deadlock situations? (i.e. when the field cannot be found due to some reason)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're code gets stuck. In my environment, it gives a nice run time exception. In any case, you've basically got two issues here:

1. Note that the "\" operator in play-json tries to find the *child* with the specified name. So you're trying to fetch the "tags" attribute out of the `<root>` object while it's actually part of the `annotation` object. So to extract it: `parsedJson \ "annotation" \ "tags"`
2. The tags are encoded in the JSON as an Object. Play-json is trying to be as type safe as possible, meaning that you can't simply "cast" the `JsObject` to a `JsString`. What you could do here, is extract the tags object as a JsObject and use its `toString` function. This will give you:

   `{"wellbeing":7,"mood":6,"memories":6,"tmr":3,"participants":3}`

   Transforming this into the desired string should be trivial.

Comment: How to extract the tags object as a JsObject? I get JsDefined.

Comment: Both my comments can be resolved using: `(json \ "annotation" \ "tags").as[JsObject]`. The `as[JsObject]` part transforms the `JsDefined` into the `JsObject`